# git option to only add or only subtract the changes

Tags: git, version-control, open-source

I often face this problem with git:
I clone a git repo of some project. Then I make changes to some source file, but I don't commit it, because my work is not complete. But I have to keep updating my repo to make it in sync with the master. So I do a 'git pull', so that my repository is up-to-date and so I can produce my patch against the latest repo. 
Now suppose I edit the file hello.c in my local clone (not yet committed) and someone else has made changes to the same file and committed it to the master repo. Now when I do 'git pull' the other person's changes get added to hello.c and the changes that I had made, get deleted. This is the natural behavior obviously. 
Is there a way to tell git to only 'add' changes and not 'subtract' anything? Or something to that effect? I don't want my changes to be deleted when I do a git pull, but also I want to work with the latest repository.

Comment: So commit your code. Why aren't you doing local commits? You must do that before a pull.

Comment: Work on a branch so that your work won't be affected by what happens on the main code lines until you decide you want it to be affected?

Comment: Read this topic also - [What's the difference between git pull and git fetch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/whats-the-difference-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- As Greg said - "Commit!". "Commit often, commit fast" is **common rule** in VCS-world for years
- Use correct commands for your tasks. If you don't know all behind the scene of `git pull` - read FM! [Learn difference between pull and fetch](http://longair.net/blog/2009/04/16/git-fetch-and-merge/) or [see at examples in Git Reference](http://gitref.org/remotes/#pull)

> The second command that will fetch down new data from a remote server
>   is `git pull`. This command will basically run a git fetch immediately
>   followed by a git merge of the branch on that remote that is tracked
>   by whatever branch you are currently in. I personally don't much like
>   this command - I prefer running fetch and merge seperately. Less
>   magic, less problems.

- Use good, bullet-proof workflow. Quote from [online git-pull(1) Manual Page](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-pull.html)

> You **never** do your own development on branches that appear on the right
>   hand side of a  colon on Pull: lines; they are to be updated
>   by git fetch. If you intend to do development derived from a remote
>   branch B, have a Pull: line to track it (i.e. Pull: B:remote-B), and
>   **have a separate branch** my-B to do your development on top of it.